# ASP Validation Controls does not work on hosting server

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have used an ASP validation Controls in web project not web site but it works fine local but it does not work on hosting server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On hosting server, in IIS Control Panel, Check whether the folder aspnet_client is there in the virtual directory listing. It consists of the webuivalidation.js file which is required for processing validations.

Running following script should fix the issue.

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework[Place .Net Ver Number here]\aspnet_regiis -c